# Mail sending is failure in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

In CodeIgniter, while using the following script for mail sending, my mail sending code fails.

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'mail',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'starttls'  => true,
    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
    'priority' => '1'
);

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com', 'Website');
$this->email->to('customersupport@abc.com');
$this->email->subject('This is an email test');
$this->email->message("gggggggg");
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: What's the meaning of failure ? Anyway maybe no SMTP configured.

Comment: What error is this giving?

Comment: I think smtp is not configured

Comment: I am getting no error. Even mail has been sent successfully if recipient mail account is gmail. Other recipient having different email account doesn't receive any mail. I am using 'protocol' => 'mail', no SMTP.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should consider using other services like Mandrill, Postmark, Sendgrid which are free for around 10K emails per month. They are easy to implement without server side setup & have libraries for CI